# Ormlite - Constructor call failing when BaseDaoImpl is extended

Tags: java, ormlite

I have the following tables -

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="b", daoClass=B_DaoImpl.class)
public class B {

   @DatabaseField
   public String b1 ;

   public B(){
     // For Ormlite
   }
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName="a", daoClass=A_DaoImpl.class)
public class A {

   @DatabaseField
   public String a1 ;

   @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
   public B b;

   public A(){
     // For Ormlite
   }
}
```

For these tables, the associated Dao and DaoImpl are as follows

```
public interface A_Dao extends Dao<A, String>{}
public interface B_Dao extends Dao<B, String>{}


public class B_DaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<User, String> implements B_Dao {

   public B_DaoImpl(ConnectionSource connectionSource) throws SQLException {
      super(connectionSource, B.class);
   }
}

public class A_DaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<User, String> implements A_Dao {

   public A_DaoImpl(ConnectionSource connectionSource) throws SQLException {
      super(connectionSource, A.class);
   }
}
```

Database helper is as follows:

```
 public class DatabaseHelperImpl extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper implements DatabaseHelper {

   private A_DaoImpl aDao = null;
   private B_DaoImpl bDao = null;

   public B_DaoImpl getBDao() throws SQLException {
       if (bDao == null) {
          bDao = getDao(B.class);
       }
       return bDao;
   }

   public A_DaoImpl getA() throws SQLException {
        if (aDao  == null ) {
          aDao = getDao(A.class);
        }
        return aDao;
   }
}
```

Now, when I try to call -

```
ADao aDao = databaseHelper.getA();
```

it errors out with the following error:

```
 Could not call the constructor in class class A_DaoImpl
```

Now, if I do not have the foriegn key in A - ie if A does not contain *public B b*, it works fine. Is there something that I am missing here?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you post the entire exception.  There should be cause information for that exception?  Also, what version of ORMLite are you using?

Comment: Yeah it's not about "correct" it's about contribution and the best answer.  If there isn't a good answer then you should answer it yourself.

Comment: I have accepted the best answers :) Thank you Gray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that there is cause message you are missing at the end of your exception stack trace.  For example, if I duplicate your example above I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not call the constructor in class class 
      com.j256.ormlite.table.CustomDaoTest$A_DaoImpl
  at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Foreign field class
>>>>      com.j256.ormlite.table.CustomDaoTest$B does not have id field  <<<<<<
  at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.configDaoInformation(FieldType.java:332)
  ...
```

Because `A` has a foreign field of class `B`, then `B` needs to have an id field.  Identity fields are required for foreign fields.

I'm sure `A` and `B` are simplistic versions of your classes so if you post more of the exception including all of the cause information, I'll edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: Thank you Gray. That indeed was the issue. I had even seen this issue while researching for this answer - but since I was having all DaoImpl etc, I got sidetracked. Thank you again. You were of great help.