# Null pointer exception when creating custom Dao with ormlite-android

Tags: ormlite

I'm trying to extend the base ORMLite DAO class so I can add some custom methods.  I've tried following the answer here, but I'm getting a null error and not sure how to cast the dao object correctly ([Ormlite - Constructor call failing when BaseDaoImpl is extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184169/ormlite-constructor-call-failing-when-basedaoimpl-is-extended)) Currently, I have the following table:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="beers", daoClass=BeerDao.class)
public class Beer {
    public static final String BEER_NAME = "name";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @DatabaseField()
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField()
    private String breweryName;

    public Beer() {}

    ... getters/setters
    }
```

The BeerDao class:

```
public class BeerDao<Beer,UUID> extends BaseDaoImpl<Beer,UUID> {

    public BeerDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource, Class<Beer> dataClass) throws SQLException {
        super(connectionSource, dataClass);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper  {
    private static final String TAG = "Database";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "brewgenius.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

    private BeerDao<Beer, UUID> beerDao = null;
    private Dao<Checkin, UUID> checkinDao = null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }

    /* ... onCreate and onUpgrade code ..*/

    /**
     * Get Beer Model DAO
     * 
     * @return Beer DAO
     */
    public BeerDao<Beer, UUID> getBeerDao() {
        if (beerDao == null) {
            try {
                beerDao = getDao(Beer.class);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return beerDao;
    }
```

}

In my activity, when I try to get the Dao, I get a null pointer exception.

```
BeerDao<Beer,UUID> dao = getHelper().getBeerDao();
```

FYI, Dao is cast to:

```
BeerDao<Beer,UUID>
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like my DatabaseConfigUtil isn't reading the DaoClass attribute.

```
public class DatabaseConfigUtil extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
        writeConfigFile("ormlite_config.txt");
    }
}
```

Removing ormlite_config.txt from DatabaseHelper's constuctor caused on-the-fly reading which correctly reads the DaoClass attribute.  Any idea why the writer isn't writing this?

Here's ormlite_config.txt

```
# --table-start--
dataClass=com.brewgenius.model.Beer
tableName=beers
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=id
columnName=_id
generatedId=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=name
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=breweryName
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
#################################
```

Comment: So it looks like the `getDao(Beer.class)` method is returning `null`.  Can you show that code and remove the debug image?  If that is calling through to `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(Class)` then something is very wrong since that routine cannot return `null`.

Comment: Gray, appreciate you responding.  I've added my code from my DatabaseHelper.  Something is very wrong...this is why I'm stumped.  The previous tutorial cast getHelper to what would be BeerDao in my example, but that also causes the Null error as well.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on @gspatel.  I'd debug it and step into the code to see where the `null` is coming from.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Okay, I've debugged and found something out!!  I was using DatabaseConfigUtil to preparse my annotations which won't write daoClass to the .txt file for some reason (i've rebuilt the project and then parsed and changed other things but the daoClass doesn't ever appear in the output of the ConfigUtil).  When I removed using the parsed file, all of my previous code worked.  I had debugged into DaoManager.lookupDao(key) where Dao<?, ?> dao = classMap.get(key); kept returning null (the my error).  Gray, any idea on why the ConfigUtil isn't capturing daoClass or if I'm doing something wrong there.