# Are ID fields inherited in ORMLite?

Tags: android, ormlite

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public abstract class AHuman
{
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    protected String login;
}
```

And the two following classes extend it:

```
@DatabaseTable(daoClass = UserDAO.class)
public class User extends AHuman
{
     User() {}

     @ForeignCollectionField
     private ForeignCollection<Person> friends;
}


@DatabaseTable(daoClass = PersonDAO.class)
public class Person extends AHuman
{
    Person() {}
}
```

When I compile and run this on my Android device I get the following errors:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not call the constructor in class class 
      com.j256.ormlite.table.CustomDaoTest$A_DaoImpl
  at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Foreign field class
>>>>      com.j256.ormlite.table.CustomDaoTest$B does not have id field  <<<<<<
  at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.configDaoInformation(FieldType.java:332)
```

This error derives from the `ForeignCollection<Person>` declared in the `User` class.

Apparently, coming from the following question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184169/ormlite-constructor-call-failing-when-basedaoimpl-is-extended), it comes from the fact that the Person class has no "id" field declared in.

But aren't the "id" fields inherited from the abtract class also included in the Child object ?

Answer (score 0):

@Id fields are inherited. Maybe the problem is that your constructors are not public (with default specifier)